# Spams accessing the server

Tags: security

I opened a small website through port forwarding to allow anyone to access my site. I didn't even post the address of this site, but some people from other countries(found out through the IP) were accessing my site. How do they know my address and what can they do in my site?

Answer (score 1):

How do they know your IP? There are bots that scan the entire internet regularly. New IPs and ports can be found quickly, and may be publicized in forums for people looking for such.

What can they do in your site? As Rickuku notes, it depends on what security you have and what is on your site.  But even static sites can be used in ways the author didn't intend and wouldn't want.  See Troy Hunt's blog (https://www.troyhunt.com/heres-why-your-static-website-needs-https/) for starters.

Since it sounds like you are just starting with this, I highly recommend you use your firewall to restrict access to your new site to just the IP you use to test it, until you are sure you're ready for the world to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, it gotten indexed by those search engine, scrapped or something of that effect.

As for the actual adverse effects it's largely depends on the site. A static site? Not much. Something like an improperly secured Wordpress/Joomla!/etc they could do some nasty things.

So if you still feels confident and safe of hosting it at your house at this point, just be sure it's up to date, firewalls are in place, etc etc etc.